# SET is not working inside loop in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, variables

I want to iterate all files of my folder based on their file extension, and file names using a batch script.

I have the below code to get the file extension, and can echo it with `%%~xa`, but when I try to define it as `file_extension`, the output just returns as `ECHO is off.`

Can someone please tell me how to do it?

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
 
for  %%a in (folder\*) do (
       
    echo Processing file = %%~nxa
    echo Processing file extension %%~xa
    echo Processing file name = %%~na
    SET file_extension = %%~xa
    echo !file_extension!
    echo %%~xa
)  
pause
```

Comment: SET is working, the issue is that you aren't using it correctly! If you change it to `echo !file_extension !`, it will work. However I would advise instead that you do it properly in the first place and use `SET file_extension=%%~xa`, or even better the recommended syntax, `Set "file_extension=%%~xa"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cmd` is not the same as the likes of `perl`, `C#` etc.

`cmd` actually uses the whitespace before and after `=` as part of the variable name and value.
Currently your code `SET file_extension = %%~xa` will create a variable with trailing whitespace `!File_extension !` and a leading space in the value.  `.txt`.

so you must set it with not whitespace before or after `=`. It is better to also use double quotes around the variable and value inclusive, to also ensure that there are not any accidental whitespace after the value. for instance `set var=val`  will create a variable of `%var%` correctly but an incorrect value of `val` .

So after all that is explained, here is a fixed version of your current code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
 
for  %%a in ("folder\*") do (
       
    echo Processing file = %%~nxa
    echo Processing file extension %%~xa
    echo Processing file name = %%~na
    set "file_extension=%%~xa"
    echo !file_extension!
    echo %%~xa
)  
pause
```